# Open Image automatically in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to load an image from a folder in Unity as soon as I press play. If a new image is added to the folder during runtime, the new image should automatically replace the old one. To do this, I think I would need to be able to automatically name the images as soon as they are loaded into the folder but I am not sure how to do this.
Currently the folder opens and I can manually select the image I want and  open it in Unity.

I would appreciate if any of you could give me an advice how I could automate the whole process.

Below you can find my current unity scene "FileExplorer". You have to create a folder with a png and change the "FOLDERNAME" and the "FOLDERPATH" in the script "FileManager" at the marked position, then everything should work like it does for me.

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/6fa821c2d0dd99469b3ef566bbf176f620220126130218/3158f0

If you don't want to use the link you can lay the script below on an Empty and add a Canvas with a Raw image to your scene. After that you put your Raw Image in the "Raw Image" Slot of the Empty.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class FileManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    string path;
    public RawImage rawImage;

    void Start()
    {
       OpenFileExplorer(); 
    }

    public void OpenFileExplorer()
    {
        path = EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel("FILENAME (.png)", "FILEPATH", "png"); // EXCHANGE "FILENAME" AND "FILEPATH"
        StartCoroutine(GetTexture());
    }

    IEnumerator GetTexture()
    {
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture("file:///" + path);

        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if(www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Texture myTexture = ((DownloadHandlerTexture)www.downloadHandler).texture;
            rawImage.texture = myTexture;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want the texture to update if the texture file is changed?

Comment: I want to be able to load a new image into the folder of my Finder and once this image is in the folder, Unity should detect this and automatically load the image onto the texture. I hope this is more understandable :)

Comment: So you want the texture to update at runtime?

Comment: yes, exactly :)

Comment: Just a heads up, anything in the namespace UnityEditor will not work at runtime.  All editor code is stripped from builds.